# Is the relation A = {(a,a), (c,c), (d,d), (b,a)} transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm working on a discrete math problem to solve for reflexive, symmetric and transitive and I'm stuck on the transitive one. How do I solve for the transitive of the following?

A = {(a,a), (c,c), (d,d), (b,a)}

This is what I understand for transitive. A relation is transitive if aRb and bRc there is a aRc So, for every (a, b) and (b, c) there is an (a, c)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are going to work on other similar problems, it might be useful for you to have a look at the past questions which are similar to this. For example, you may go through the post listed among related questions (like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404244/why-is-this-relation-r-a-b-b-c-c-a-transitive)) or you can try to search for similar questions using [some reasonable tags and keywords](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelations%5D+transitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bit confusing using the same letters in two different meanings. So I will rephrase the definition of transitive relation (simply by changing the names of the variables):

> Relation $A$ on the set $S$ is transitive if for any $x,y,z\in S$ $$(x,y)\in A \land (y,z)\in A \Rightarrow (x,z)\in A.$$

So you have to check whether this is true for elements from the given set, which is  - I assume - $S=\{a,b,c,d\}$.

This would mean trying $4^3$ possibilities. Luckily we do not have to try the pairs which are not in $A$. (For example, the implication is clearly true if $x=c$, $y=d$ since $(c,d)\notin A$.)  This reduces the number of pairs we have to check.

We can also notice that if $x=y$, then the above implication says
$$(x,x)\in A \land (x,z)\in A \Rightarrow (x,z)\in A$$
which is always true. (Basically the same arguments works for the case $y=z$.)

Since in $A$ we have only one pair where both coordinates are not the same and we are now only checking the pairs such that $x\ne y$, we only have to look at $x=b$, $y=a$. But if $y=a$ then the only possibility such that $(y,z)\in A$ is $z=a$. But we have already taken care of the case $y=z$.

In short: Since, for this particular relation $A$, we have either $x=y$ or $y=z$ whenever both $(x,y)\in A$ and $(y,z)\in A$, the relation is transitive.